# Blob GetBinaryStream requires closing?

Tags: java, oracle, blob

I have following code:

```
       BlobDomain blob = mrow.getFileText();
       StringBuffer o = new StringBuffer("");
       if (blob != null) {
           InputStream in = null;
           try {
               in = blob.getBinaryStream();
               byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
               int count = 0;
               while ((count = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                   o.append(new String(buf));
                   buf = new byte[1024];
               }

           }catch(Exception e){

               }finally{
               try{
                   if(in != null)
                    in.close();

               }catch(Exception ee){}
               }
```

does the blob need any sort of closing?

Comment: Just assume that all input streams need closing, then you don't have to remember which ones don't.

Comment: I always close resources. If they don't need closing, then it won't do any harm. But if they do require closing, the **not** closing them is really bad

Comment: i dont see a blob.close in this case. how do i close then?

Comment: Close them **always**. The fact that it passes all the unit tests. Does not guarantee, it will work correctly in multi-user environments.

Answer (score 2):

> Blob GetBinaryStream requires closing?

Possibly not.  But it is a good idea to close it anyway.

However, I would strongly recommend that you use Java 7+ "try with resources" syntax.  It is much cleaner, simpler, more reliable.  Like this:

```
       try (InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream()) {
           byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
           int count = 0;
           while ((count = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
               o.append(new String(buf));
               buf = new byte[1024];
           }
       }
```

There is an implicit `finally` that closes the `in` stream AND deals with exceptions that might be thrown by the `close()` call.

> does the blob need any sort of closing?

The `Connection`, `Statement` and/or `ResultSet` you got the `Blob` from need to be "managed".  If you do that properly, I don't think a `Blob` needs to be managed any further ... though you can optionally `free()` it to release resources earlier.

---

I hope that the exception handling in your code is nothing like your real code.  You are doing two BAD things in your exception handling:

- You are "squashing" exceptions; i.e. catching them and throwing away all of the evidence.  This make after-the-fact debugging very difficult.
- Catching `Exception` is almost always a mistake.  You are liable to catch all sorts of exceptions that you are not expecting to happen; e.g. NPEs caused by bugs in your code.

Doing both of those things at the same time is ... REALLY BAD.

And if you *insist* on doing the resource management (closing) by hand, the you should do it in a `finally` block.  (Read about it in the Java Tutorial, etc.)